# Currently some Meta sites do not allow me to login

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login, auto-login

This started happening a couple of days ago.  When navigating to the Information Security Meta page (after being logged into InfoSec) I'm greeted with the **Sign Up** and **Login** buttons.  If I click **Login** the webpage reloads, but no change to my login status.

I seem to be able to go to other Meta sites just fine.  When talking with others on the DMZ they seem to be able to access InfoSec Meta.  Any thoughts as to why this might be happening?

I can access:

- Stack Overflow Meta
- Super User Meta

I can't access:

- Information Security Meta
- Unix & Linux Meta
- Area 51

Comment: Are you going straight to the meta site or visiting the main site first?

Comment: Also HTTPS isn't fully supported yet.

Comment: Ah I see this now.  Going straight to Meta without HTTPS Everywhere enabled brings up the certificate error that fails.

Comment: So what happens if you use the HTTP link instead?

Comment: @ChrisF Everything works fine with HTTP.  I answered my own question with the relevant certificate error I receive, and the URL difference between the meta sites.  I'm sure once the Meta sites get synced with the correct cert name HTTPS Everywhere will allow me to login again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this appears to be an issue with HTTPS Everywhere.  Navigating straight to meta.security.stackexchange.com gives the following certificate error:

> The identity of this website was not verified.  Server's certificate
>   does not match the URL.

Server's Certificate URL: `ssl8217.cloudflare.com`

Stack Overflow Meta's server certificate responds with: `*.stackexchange.com`

There in lies the problem.  Once SE fixes the certificates used on all Meta sites HTTPS Everywhere will most likely stop failing, and allow me to login.

Comment: They're more likely to change the meta urls from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com` (it's to do with minimising the number of certificates and where the wildcards can be), which is quite a task (rewriting existing urls etc.)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  I'm just curious why it was working last week, and not this week.  But at least I understand what's going on now.